# How to filter the dmesg log to see only the errors

Tags: logs, dmesg

I am in ubuntu, when I write dmesg the error messages appear in red, how could I print in the console only those?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use `--level` option described in [`man dmesg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/dmesg.1.html):

> ```
>   -l, --level list
>          Restrict output to the given (comma-separated) list of levels.
>          For example:
>
>                 dmesg --level=err,warn
>
>          will print error and warning messages only.  For all supported
>          levels see the --help output.
> ```

Comment: To get most error levels/priorities i'd suggest using `dmesg -T --level=emerg,alert,crit,err,warn` since the docs mention `err,warn` but there are more important levels above the err. Of course confirm with `dmesg --help` to see what log levels you have available.

Answer (score 4):

**Direct Answer**

```
dmesg --level=emerg,alert,crit,err
```

This is what most people are going to be looking for.  Add or remove any from the following list of eight, ordered by severity.

```
   emerg - system is unusable    
   alert - action must be taken immediately
    crit - critical conditions
     err - error conditions
    warn - warning conditions   
  notice - normal but significant condition
    info - informational    
   debug - debug-level messages
```

**Alternate Answer** 
I like to use grep to quickly filter dmesg output results and, bonus, you can use it at the end of many show commands.  The `-i` means case insensitive.  Reference: https://www.howtogeek.com/449335/how-to-use-the-dmesg-command-on-linux/.

```
dmesg | grep -i "error"
```

**Another Option**

```
journalctl -p 0..3
```

This looks at similar information a different way.  Modify the severity filtering (the `0` through `3`) but just use numbers 0 through 7 for the same concept as dmesg, without having to remember those keywords.

Credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/1245985/192800

**The Rabbit Hole** 
Another way to think of this is to look at the actual log file using any method you choose, instead of working around the limitations of dmesg.  This can be done broadly to any file and with limitless potential using things like regular expressions.  Here is a demonstration of both approaches to show the last `-n` number of entries.

```
tail -n 20 /var/log/dmesg
dmesg | tail -n 20
```